# Leverage multi-core CPU in setup:di:compile command Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cli, setup-di-compile

When developing for Magento 2 one of the more time consuming system tasks is running `bin/magento setup:di:compile`.

Since the compiler executes several tasks in a queue, I'm thinking executing them all at once would increase compiling speed by using a separate php process / core per task?

This is of course only possible when the queued tasks don't depend on each others execution result.

I'm not very familiar with the details of the compiling process, maybe someone can elaborate whether this solution would be feasible / possible at all?

Comment: When you developing for Magento 2 you should not run setup:di:compile. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Shouldn't you do this to make the constructor dependency injection take effect? I've set the mode to developer mode, but still I need to run that command. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: As maximum, you need cleanup var/generated folder and clean caches. No need to run setup:di:compile

Comment: I see indeed, thanks a lot. What about the var/di folder? If you add an answer I'll accept and close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you developing for Magento 2 you should not run `setup:di:compile`.

As the maximum, you need cleanup var/generated folder and clean caches.

`var/di` folder contains serialized data about class constructor parameters/inheritance that not need in developer mode.

Comment: Very interesting information... :)